# How do I open a .prl file?

Tags: iphone, ios, mac, file, cellular-carriers

What program can I use to open a .prl file? I want to view the preferred roaming list from my carrier bundle, but I don’t know which software will open this file.

Comment: [Preferred Roaming List (PRL) Tools](http://www.cdg.org/roaming/roaming_resources/PRLTools/index.asp) - apparently Windows 7 (or XP) & Excel required.

Comment: Looks like they are some sort of database file. You could try just a text editor but you are likely to just get some binary junk... Otherwise it looks like you are stuck opening those in WIndows with Excel as klanomath  seems to have found tools to open those files, above.

Comment: @klanomath thank you so much! Would windows 10 work?

Comment: @user295021 I think it's rather depending on the Excel version than the system version. I'd have to test in a VM whether it works in W10 & MS Office 2016/Office 365